# Missing "Hamburger Icon" in Angular Material App

Tags: angular, angular-material, breakpoints, sidenav

I am new to Angular world and I want to make a Dashboard (with SideNav and TopNav) with Angular Material. So, I installed everything and added the Angular Material library via :

```js
ng add @angular/material
```

I added also the ready to use component for teh sideNav and TopNav and called it "mynav":

```js
ng add @angular/material:nav mynav
```

when I run "**ng serve -o**" I got the sideNav and TopNav as wanted, but the HAMBURGER ICON to show and hide the sideNav is missing in the Desktop (or in any other widescreen device) view. 
[See image here: [image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiDfp.jpg).
In the mobile (or in any other small screen device) view though, the "Hamburger menu" is visible and working (toggling function: open and hide the SideNav).  [See image here: [image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZinMB.jpg).

How to get the "Hamburger Icon" appearing in the big screens like laptops or desktops? I know i should edit the breakpoints for that, but how? Here is the generated code in "**mynav.component.html**" :

```js
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav #drawer class="sidenav" fixedInViewport="true"
      [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
      [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'"
      [opened]="!(isHandset$ | async)">
    <mat-toolbar>Menu</mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 3</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">
      <button
        type="button"
        aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
        mat-icon-button
        (click)="drawer.toggle()"
        *ngIf="isHandset$ | async">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <span>project1</span>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <!-- Add Content Here -->
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Comment: Simple: Your "Toggle sidenav" icon button has an `ngIf` conditional which indicates that the button is shown based on whether the `isHandset$` variable is truthy. The schematic for the sidenav also generates component code for that `isHandset$` variable which uses the Angular CDK's [`BreakpointObserver`](https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/api#BreakpointObserver).

Answer (score 1):

Reiterating what I've commented on your question:

> Simple: Your "Toggle sidenav" icon button has an `ngIf` conditional which indicates that the button is shown based on whether the `isHandset$` variable is truthy. The schematic for the sidenav also generates component code for that `isHandset$` variable which uses the Angular CDK's [`BreakpointObserver`](https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/api#BreakpointObserver).

Looking at the [schematic code](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/schematics/ng-generate/nav/files/__path__/__name%40dasherize%40if-flat__/__name%40dasherize__.component.ts.template) for the `nav` schematic, you can see that the `isHandset$` variable is defined as follows:

```js
isHandset$: Observable<boolean> = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset)
    .pipe(
      map(result => result.matches),
      shareReplay()
    );

constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {}
```

What the above code does in a nutshell:

1. Observes the document for any changes to the window dimensions. (It uses media queries under the hood by adding event listeners and automatically removing the listeners)
2. The `observe` method of `BreakpointObserver` is documented on the [API documentation](https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/api#BreakpointObserver) as follows:

   > Gets an observable of results for the given queries that will emit new results for any changes in matching of the given queries.
   >
   > Returns a stream of matches for the given queries. (Type: `Observable<BreakpointState>`
3. [`BreakpointState`](https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/api#BreakpointState) is an interface which contains 2 properties:

   - `breakpoints: { [key: string]: boolean; }` - A key boolean pair for each query provided to the observe method, with its current matched state.
   - `matches: boolean` - Whether the breakpoint is currently matching.
4. As such, the stream is piped through a [`map`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/map) pipe which maps the result to the `matches` property.
5. And as a result, the menu icon button is hidden based on whether the media query is matched.

The full list of predefined breakpoints (including `Breakpoints.Handset`) are listed in the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview#default-breakpoints).

The `BreakpointObserver` class is also extensively documented under the [Layout section on the CDK docs](https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview#breakpointobserver).

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely you did not import the required modules for it.

You will need to register the `mat-icon` component, as you currently using it for your menu's hamburger icon. Therefore, you will need to have to import the `MatIconModule`, which declares the component. Same goes for the `MatButtonModule`.

On the module that uses the navigation menu, make the following changes:

```
import { MatButtonModule, MatIconModule } from '@angular/material';    

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule,
    // other imported modules
  ],
  // others
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the quick answer, but these modules are already automatically imported in the file app.componont.ts :

Comment: @anyname Hmm.. Shouldn't they be imported in the .module.ts file instead?

Comment: they are in deed imported automatically to app.module.ts as well. But i think, that by default the Hamburger Icon appears only on small devices. it's better then to look for a method to add a toogling button to the desktop view as well

Comment: @anyname Ahh, does it show when you toggle the screen size then? If yes, you will need to overwrite the CSS Media Queries!

Comment: i think it's better to let it so, and add a new toggling button to hide the half of sideNav and let icons visible! thanks @wentjun for the support.

Comment: @anyname You're welcome! All the best with the project!

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you asked the question quite a long time ago but I am gonna post anyway. I have a very similar issue where instead of the icon, literally the word "menu" is shown. I copied your code to see if I get the same result, and by elimination, I figured that the below line of code is leading to your icon not showing

```
    *ngIf="isHandset$ | async">
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove below *ngif condition from button tag and menu icon will appear, it worked for me

*ngIf="isHandset$ | async"